# Experimentally Measuring the Velocity of Water coming out of an Orifice

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, experimental-technique

I plan on doing an investigation into Torricelli's Law, where I will be looking at one of the following:

1. How the cross-sectional area of an orifice affects the velocity of water coming out of it (constant height).
2. How the height of an orifice affects the velocity of water coming out of it (constant orifice area).

However, I was unsure about how to accurately measure the velocity of water coming out of the orifice. Videos on YouTube only suggest one method, which is using the horizontal and vertical displacements of the water stream to calculate velocity. However, when I've done this experimentally I've found an about $15\%$ error compared to expected values. The process is also not very exact per se, i.e. it is hard to judge the exact marking of a ruler that the stream lands on.

Therefore, I was wondering if there were any *accurate* means to measure the velocity of water coming out of an orifice, using equipment typically found in a school laboratory.

Comment: How did you calculate the "expected values"? A simple method to get a more precise location of where the water stream intersects a plane is by letting it fall through the plane and to intercept the two edges of the stream with a sharp edge. Even small disturbances of the stream by the edge should be easily noticeable.

Comment: @FlatterMann I used the formula on Wikipedia, specifically $v=\sqrt{\frac{2gh}{1-\frac{A_o}{A_b}}}$, where $A_o$ is the cross-sectional area of the orifice and $A_b$ is the cross-sectional area of the bottle/can.

Comment: Slide a ruler edge forth and back in a freely falling section of the stream. When you hit the stream it will be very visibly disturbed. That should give you the location of the stream in the plane of the ruler with sub-mm precision. Alternative use an optical sensor (slotted optocoupler). Those are less than a dollar and should give a very precise signal without disrupting the stream at all.

Comment: Safe to assume laser doppler velocimetry is outside your budget?  :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Water is incompressible. So you can put a bucket under your stream and let it run for some time. That way you measure the volume of water coming out per time [units m$^3/$s]. Divide by the cross-sectional area of the orifice [m$^2$] to get the water speed [m$/$s].

Comment: +1, putting a weight sensor under the water reservoir would allow measuring water speed in real time

Comment: @bobflux You'd probably want to account for the fact that the water is falling, though.

Comment: Could put the scale under the tank the water flows out of, if it comes out of the side the vertical reaction force should be zero

Comment: pay attention at non-starionary terms with this method. If the outflow is approximately horizontal, $\dot m = - \frac{d M(t)}{d t} = -\frac{1}{g}\frac{dN}{dt} + \frac{1}{g}\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\int_{V(t)} \rho w(\mathbf{r},t)$, being $M(t)$ the mass of fluid in the tank, $V(t)$ the volume of fluid in the tank, $w(\mathbf{r},t)$ the vertical component of the velocity field, and $N$ the vertical reaction from the balance

Comment: to cut a long story short, if one can measure the volume (equivalent to measure the level of the free surface), $\dot m = -\frac{d M}{dt} = -\rho \frac{d V}{dt}$, while the normal reaction measured by a balance includes the unsteady contribution

Comment: This is how we measure flow rates in the field, especially very _low_ flow rates. In fact there are commercial sensors that operate in this manner. The principal is very easy to implement in the classroom.

Comment: If you can make the velocity constant (such as by relying on a gravity fed reservoir that you keep filled to a known level during the experiment), you don't even need to do the measurement while the water is flowing

Comment: @rfl So if I understand your comment correctly, I would check the volume (probably using an analytical mass balance) of the bucket at a certain time, and divide that volume by both the time elapsed and the cross-sectional area of the orifice?

Comment: Yes. Or you use a beaker from your chemistry lab. Or put it on a balance, which anyway is a nice alternative solution to your problem, so I would try out both.

Answer (score 3):

A simple method to get a more precise location of where the water stream intersects a plane is by letting it fall through the plane and to intercept the two edges of the stream with a sharp edge. Even small disturbances of the stream by the edge should be easily noticeable. I would guestimate that you will get sub-mm precision from that, i.e. well below 1% errors on the velocity if done well. A physicist I knew once did the opposite: he let the water stream intercept a beam of light (a slotted optocoupler sensor costs less than a dollar these days) and regulated the height in the reservoir using that signal. I think he got better than 0.1% errors out of that setup.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by "intercept the two edges of the stream with a sharp edge". Is there perhaps a video or lab schematic where this is shown?

Answer (score 2):

With a "high speed" camera, and assuming a near laminar flow, you could cut the flow with something like a fan blade and measure that edge created using a scale behind the water with respect to the camera.

Another is if you used a plunger (imagine a large syringe) then you can measure its position which directly gives you changes in volume.  The plunger friction creates an unknown to your pressure though.

Answer (score 1):

I did some work on this once and came across a range of references on this topic.  I can't remember if they specifically cover what you ask for here, but might be in one of these:

Paulo Murilo Castro de Oliveira, Antonio Delfino, Eden Viera Costa and Carlos Alberto Faria Leite,“Pin-hole water flow from cylindrical bottles”, Phys. Educ. 35 110 (March 2000)

Rod Cross, “Filling or draining a water bottle with two holes”, Phys. Educ. 51 045014 (July 2016).

Stephen M. Durbin, “Combined demonstration of non-viscous and viscous flow”, Am. J. Phys. 87(47), 305 (March 2019).

Laura Pavesi, “Investigating Torricell’s Law (and More) with a 19th-Century Bottle”, Phys. Teach.57, 106 (January 2019).

Answer (score 0):

Place a measurement grid by the stream and start filming. As clear water flows, add food color to the water. Measure the movement of the front of the colored water versus the grid. Preferably, use clear pipes to allow measurement of the water velocity before it leaves the orifice.